# Hard refresh on Internet Explorer

Tags: 8.0, internet-explorer

How do I tell Internet Explorer in Windows Phone 8 to refresh the page by sending new request to server and not displaying data from cache (hard refresh)? Something like pressing CTRL-F5 in a PC browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no direct way (yet) to do what you are trying to.

However, an indirect way of doing this is to clear your cache by [following the instructions here](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-ca/how-to/wp8/web/change-privacy-and-other-browser-settings).

Alternatively, you could consider using a browser other than Internet Explorer and try and make feature requests for these. [Here is a discussion](http://forums.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-8/221708-best-ie10-alternative-web-browser.html) about alternative browsers on Windows Phone.